# How to format the current date with Suffix to Superscript?

Tags: java, android

I am using the `SimpleDateFormatter`

```
 public static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT_FULL_FULL_SPACES = 
     new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

and `Current Date` is passed at that time, It should display as
      `1st JULY 2014` where st should be superscript.

How can I go further ?

Comment: And where are you displaying the text ? In a `TextView`?

Comment: yes in TextView the date should say: 1 = 1st
2 = 2nd
3 = 3rd
4 = 4th
5 = 5th
6 = 6th
7 = 7th
8 = 8th
9 = 9th
10 = 10th
11 = 11th
12 = 12th
13 = 13th
14 = 14th
15 = 15th
16 = 16th
17 = 17th
18 = 18th
19 = 19th
20 = 20th
21 = 21st
22 = 22nd
23 = 23rd
24 = 24th
25 = 25th
26 = 26th
27 = 27th
28 = 28th
29 = 29th
30 = 30th
31 = 31st

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597223/android-textview-superscript

Comment: yes... How to add suffix after the date I am passing current date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create these methods

```
private String getFormatedDate(){
        String dayNumberSuffix = getDayNumberSuffix(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" d'" + dayNumberSuffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

    private String getDayNumberSuffix(int day) {
        if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
            return "<sup>th</sup>";
        }
        switch (day % 10) {
            case 1:
                return "<sup>st</sup>";
            case 2:
                return "<sup>nd</sup>";
            case 3:
                return "<sup>rd</sup>";
            default:
                return "<sup>th</sup>";
        }
    }
```

**How to call?**

```
String str = getFormatedDate();
        txtDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

**OutPut :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The superscript part isn't the first tricky part here - although it's not clear *how* you'd want that to be represented anyway (HTML with `<sup>` tags? something else?)

The first tricky part is knowing how to get the ordinal (`st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`) and doing that appropriately for different cultures (which can have very different rules). This isn't something that `SimpleDateFormat` supports, as far as I'm aware. You should also be aware that different cultures might not use `dd MMMM yyyy` as their normal full date format - it could look very odd to some people.

I would think very carefully about:

- Which locales you need to support
- Whether you *really* need the ordinal part
- How you want the superscript to be represented in a string

If you only need to handle English, then the ordinal part isn't too hard (you can probably find examples of a `String getOrdinal(int value)` method online, or write your own in 5 minutes). If you're *also* happy to always use a "day first" format, then you'd probably only need to format the month and year in `SimpleDateFormat`, e.g.

```
public String formatWithOrdinal(Calendar calendar) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    formatter.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    return day + toSuperscript(getOrdinal(day)) + formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Where `toSuperscript` would use HTML or whatever you need to superscript the value.

In short, you have a lot of separable concerns here - I strongly suggest you separate them, work out your exact requirements, and then implement them as simply as you can.

Comment: what is getOrdinal can you explain with whole method ?

Comment: and toSuperScript also  ?

Comment: @ABHStech: I couldn't possibly explain `toSuperScript` as you haven't explained how you want the superscript to be represented. I explained that you should search to find other examples of creating ordinal values from numbers - and that it wouldn't take long to implement it yourself. You shouldn't regard Stack Overflow as a code-writing service - you need to be able to put effort in yourself. As it happens, you were given complete code by Prakash - but you shouldn't regard this as the norm.