# Add * at the top right corner of Text in android

Tags: android

is it possible to add " * " symbol at the top|right corner in string in android Text View.i wish to display the text like "fire™". in that instead of "tm" i wish to add " * ".

Comment: You can use HTML in a TextView as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597223/android-textview-superscript).

Comment: You can use `Superscript` for it or use `Spannable` string.

Comment: Do you want to  * at the and of the _TEXT/ TEXTVIEW_ ???

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in two way

Method 1 : using [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))  `<sup>` tag

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)
mTextView .setText(Html.fromHtml("fire<sup>*</sup>"));
```

Method 2 : using [SuperscriptSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html#SuperscriptSpan())

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)
SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder ("fire*");
s.setSpan (new SuperscriptSpan(), 4, s.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(s);
```

Note : replace `R.id.text` with your textview id.

And **Recommended** way is to use `SuperscriptSpan`(see method 2) because `Html.fromHtml` is a costlier operation as it involves parsing the Html.

To see difference see [Spannable Vs Typeface Vs Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552437/spannable-vs-typeface-vs-html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate one HTML String and then you can do this, just checkout below code:

```
String mainString="YOUR TEXT<sup>SIGN TO SHOW-*</sup>";
YOURTEXTVIEW.setText(Html.fromHtml(mainString));
```